# How to catch Exceptions occured in Catch block in Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I need to handle Exceptions which are raised by Catch block code in Java

Comment: then write code inside the catch block.

Answer (score 4):

Example, to "handle" an Exception:

```
try 
{
 // try do something
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    //Do some more
}
```

More info see: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

However if you want another catch in your try catch, you can do the following:

```
 try 
     {
           //Do something
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
            System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());

            try
            {
                 // Try something else
            }
            catch ( Exception e1 )
            {
                System.out.println("Caught Another exception: " + e1.getMessage());                     
            }
     }
```

Be careful with nested try/catch, when your try catch is getting to complex/large, consider splitting it up into its own method. For example:

```
try {
    // do something here
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    foo();
}

private void foo()
{
    try {
        // do something here (when we have the IO exception)
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Caught another exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cascading try/catch (like in most of the other answers), I advise you to **call another method**, executing the required operations. Your code will be **easier to maintain** by this way.
In this method, put a try/catch block to protect the code.

Example :

```
public int classicMethodInCaseOfException(int exampleParam) {
    try {
        // TODO
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        methodInCaseOfException();
    }
}


public int methodInCaseOfException()
{
    try {
        // TODO
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch block any where in methods or in block, so you can write try catch in catch block as well.

```
try {

// master try

}catch(Exception e){
// master catch

try {
// child try in master catch

}catch(Exception e1){
// child catch in master catch

}
}//master catch
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as you would do in an usual try/catch situation :

```
try{
    throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception e1){
    try{
        throw new Exception();
    }catch(Exception e2){
    //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new try catch block in your main catch block.

```
try
      {
         int b=10/0;
      }catch(ArithmeticException e)
      {
         System.out.println("ArithmeticException occurred");
         try
         {
         int c=20/0;
         }catch(ArithmeticException e1)
         {
            System.out.println("Another ArithmeticException occurred");
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most clean way is to **create method which is catching the exceptions occurs in its body**. However it can be very dependent to the situation and type of code you are dealing with.

One example of what you are asking about is closing a `Stream` which is opened in a `try`-`catch`-`finally` block. For example:

```
package a;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("temp.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //TODO: Log the exception and handle it, 
            //          for example show a message to the user
        } finally {
            //out.close(); //Second level exception is 
                           //  occurring in closing the
                           //  Stream. Move it to a new method:
            closeOutPutStreamResource(out); 
        }
    }

    private static void closeOutPutStreamResource(OutputStream out){
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: log the exception and ignore 
            //          if it's not important
            // OR
            // Throw an instance of RuntimeException 
            //      or one of it's subclasses
            //      which doesn't make you to catch it
            //      using a try-catch block (unchecked)
            throw new CloseOutPutStreamException(e);
        }
    }
}

class CloseOutPutStreamException extends RuntimeException{

    public CloseOutPutStreamException() {
        super();
    }

    public CloseOutPutStreamException(String message, Throwable cause,
            boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    }

    public CloseOutPutStreamException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public CloseOutPutStreamException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public CloseOutPutStreamException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Here I illustrated a situation which the second level exception is occurring in the `finally` block, but the same can apply for the exceptions occur in the `catch` block.

In my point of view writing methods such as `closeOutPutStreamResource` can be useful because they are packaging a boiler plate code for handling very common exceptions and they are making your codes more elegant.

Also it would be your choice to `catch` and log the exception in `closeOutPutStreamResource` or to `throw` it to other layers of your program. But it would be more elegant to wrap this unimportant checked exceptions into `RuntimeException` without a need for catching.

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to have a nested try-catch block when catch block throws Exception as all answers here suggest. You can enclose the caller method with try-catch to handle that Exception.